# How to get a row count for a table that does not display all rows at once?

Tags: java, selenium

I have a table that when the page is fully displayed has a row count of 20 rows. However, if there is more than 20, and the user scrolls down additional rows are added. Since it only gets the initial row count, I can never find the element I'm trying to search for.

What I have right now is something along these lines.

```
        boolean isFound = false;
        List<WebElement> rowList = webdriver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'requestRow')]"));
        int rowCount = rowList.size();
        String rowNum = null;

     for (int i = 1; i <=rowCount+1; i++){
            rowNum = Integer.toString(i);   
}
```

Any idea of how I can have the table expanded and capture the new value?

Comment: you can go with the loop and use `find_elements` and if size =0 then scroll all the way to the last row (you can use actions for this). Then the loop will do the same again, break the loop when the size >0 or lastVisibleRow = CurrentVisibleRow. Just  a thought.

Comment: Get the current row count and store it. Scroll down to the bottom of the page, get the current count and compare it to the stored value. If it's greater, new rows have been added... loop again. Keep looping until the new count equals the old count. You can also look for your desired element inside that loop and quit if you find it or the count is the same (element wasn't present).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so what I did was create a list based on the current row count.

I then loop through the list incrementing one each time. If the number I'm looking for is found in the table, it does what I need doing. If it gets to a number higher than the current count of rows, I click the load more button, add the new value to my row count, and keep searching.